# How to use access all rows of type List<T> in C# .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Model called `SalesItemModel` which has properties such as `SaleItemId, SalesID, ProductID, Quantity, and UnitPrice`. I pull list from database using `SalesItemService.ListSalesItemsDataBySaleID(salesID)`.

```
public class SalesItemModel
{
    public int SalesItemID { get; set; }
    public int SalesID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public double Quantity { get; set; }

}
```

Pulling Sales Items:

```
var salesItem = SalesItemService.ListSalesItemsDataBySaleID(SalesID);
```

And I want to access quantity and product ID of every row of the returned list to edit data on stock table using those data.

Comment: Hey, please post code snippets inside your answer and not via links to photos for easier reproducibility :)

Comment: `var` isn't a particularly descriptive type if you're expecting us to figure out all the code you've not bothered to post or explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to access the data in list, you can try the below loop.

```
foreach(var item in salesItem)
{
item.Quantity = 10;
item.ProductId = 20;
}
```

Comment: It helps a lot I successfully implemented using your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tests = new List<Test>
{
    new Test{Name = "Abc", Age = 1},
    new Test{Name = "Abc2", Age = 12},
    new Test{Name = "Abc3", Age = 13},
    new Test{Name = "Abc4", Age = 14},
};

tests = tests.Select(x=>
{
    x.Age = 2;
    
    return x;
}).ToList();
```

Example which you can use.